# Identifying the version of ATI Catalyst drivers

Tags: version, amd-catalyst

I have bought a new video card based on the **ATI Radeon HD 5670** chipset.

I couldn't make it work with the latest ATI Catalyst drivers found on their website, only the drivers found on the CD delivered with the card worked.

How can I know the version of Catalyst that is installed on my PC (running Windows 7 64-bits)?

The ATI Catalyst Control Center returns the following information:

```
Driver Packaging Version    8.673-091110a-092263C   
Provider    ATI Technologies Inc.   
2D Driver Version   8.01.01.973 
2D Driver File Path /REGISTRY/MACHINE/SYSTEM/ControlSet001/Control/CLASS/{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}/0000    
Direct3D Version    8.14.10.0708    
OpenGL Version  6.14.10.9120    
Catalyst™ Control Center Version    2009.1110.2225.40230
```

I do not recognize anything pointing to a "marketing version". The website says [**the current version of Catalyst is 10.2**](http://game.amd.com/us-en/drivers_catalyst.aspx?p=win7/windows-7-64bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and run **[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/download/siw.exe)**. In the left-hand navigation pane under **Hardware**, highlight **Video**. And here's a **[list](http://www.filehippo.com/download_ati_catalyst_vista_64/history/)** and download links for older versions, going back about one year.

Here's a list of [Previous Catalyst™ Drivers and ATI Multimedia Software for Windows XP Professional/Home Edition](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/previous/Pages/radeonaiw_xp.aspx) (which includes the **internal version**). There's a similar list for [Vista 64-bit](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/previous/Pages/radeonaiw_vista64.aspx) (but there isn't any internal version listed here), but I suppose they are pretty much the same version numbers. From that list I gather your current driver is from the Catalyst Suite 9.11. The current Catalyst Suite 10.2 features the internal version 8.70.

Comment: It says "Driver Version 8.673.0.0", nothing like 10.2, or 9.x or 8.y, ... Same with Lavalys Everest and CPUID PC Wizard 2010.

Comment: @Snark - On the CD there is always the original driver that was current when the the series of video cards was first released, if you want newer versions, you'll have to download them.

Comment: yes but the newer driver on the website would not recognize the card, that's why I want to confirm the version on the CD is newer (or a beta version) than the one on the website.

Comment: @Snark - did you have a look at the date of the files on CD? those drivers on the CD are version 8.x, all these programs don't lie to you :)

Comment: @Molly @Snark The confusing here most likely stems from the fact that the Catalyst software suite and the Catalyst drivers themselves have separate versioning.  Catalyst 10.x is currently using 8.x drivers.

Comment: @phoebus - actually, you're right, i'm using the barebone driver version 8.65 (can't stand their bloated addons) which i have extracted from the Catalyst Suite 9.9

Comment: Apparently when I installed the card, only 10.1 was out. I tried 10.2 yesterday and it worked. And in the ATI CCC Information screen, it now says clearly "Catalyst 10.2". I suppose the drivers on the CD were older ones or still in beta.

Answer (score 2):

This part tells you the version:

> Catalyst™ Control Center Version    2009.1110.2225.40230

Catalyst is currently released on a monthly basis and the version number is `year.month` as integers.

The above number says this build was done on November 10 2009 so the version is 9.11.

Is [this](http://game.amd.com/us-en/drivers_catalyst.aspx?p=win7/windows-7-64bit) the driver you downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I can firmly confirm the statements from Snark & Molly7244!

A few days ago I got myself the SAPPHIRE/ATI Radeon HD5670. The package contains exactly the same versions mentioned above (CATALYST 2009.1110.2225.40230 / Driver Ver.:  8.673-091110a-092263C)

Currently I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (build 7100 or RC1). It is interesting to see that I'm not alone with this .... and that the issue is not fixed in the final version of Windows 7.

At least I found some kind of "workarround" updating CCC and card drivers. Just reboot your machine and open the recovery menu (F8) from Windows. Choose to boot up with GUI at basic [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) setings (640x480). When your system is ready to work, open the [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) and select the entry "ATI Radeon HD 5600 series" and hit "delete" to remove that one (don´t reboot!).

Then you can start the regular installation routine (take the newest version) and install everything the Radeon installer recommends. Afterwards, shut down your machine completely! Now start again the way you allways do. Ready!

Maybe that this solution doesn't work for you because of different hardware and software. But I guess it's worth trying!